# Lua Pattern - How get the required string using this lua pattern

Tags: lua

```
local invoiceData =
[[I N V O I C E
Invoice No. :
ABCDEFG125469857
Invoice Date May
2012
]]
```

The pattern I am using is

```
 print (string.match(invoiceData,'\nInvoice Date (.-)\n'))
```

I want to fetch the string **invoice date** as **MAY12**. or **0512**.. please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of matching with `.-`, be more specific and use `%w+` (alpha-nums) and `%d+` (digits) to match the month and year.

The script:

```
local invoiceData =
[[I N V O I C E
Invoice No. :
ABCDEFG125469857
Invoice Date May
2012
]]

month, year = string.match(invoiceData,'Invoice%s+Date%s+(%w+)%s+%d*(%d%d)')
print(month, year)
```

will print:

```
May    12
```

Comment: The OP does not want the century. So this use `%d%d(%d%d)` in the last part. OTOH, your pattern is more robust just in case.

Comment: @lhf, good point. I adjusted my pattern from `(%d+)` to `%d*(%d%d)` which will match both the input `"... 2012"` and `"... 12"` as `"12"`